# how to new an array base on another array,and delete duplicate value.and change value

Tags: javascript, object

how to new an array base on another array,and delete duplicate value.and change value

```
originalData = [{id:1,count:1},{id:1,count:1},{id:1,count:1},{id:2,count:1}];
newData = [{id:1,count:3},{id:2,count:1}]
```

i tried this:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rayking/aqywpcxe/)

Comment: by writing the required code. Let us know what you have tried

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove Duplicates from JavaScript Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I have needed to do this before too and I remember your question being answered here:
[Remove Duplicates from JavaScript Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array)

You just need to modify the code slightly. If you need help with that change your question.